# Node JS/azure functions passing video information back from api call

Tags: node.js, video, promise, azure-functions, chunks

So essentially, what my api call does is it 1) takes in video data using parse multipart, 2) converts that video data to a real mp4 file using ffmpeg, and then 3) is supposed to send back the video data to the client in the response body.

Steps 1 and 2 work perfectly - it's that third step that I am stuck on.

The api call creates the Out.mp4 file, but when I try and read its info using createReadStream, the chunks array doesn't populate, and a null context.res body is returned.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can pass back the video info properly so as to be able to convert the video info back to a playable mp4 file on the client's side.

Also, lmk if you have any questions or things I can clarify.

Here is the api call index.js file

````
const fs = require("fs");


module.exports=async function(context, req){

    try{
    //Get the input file setup
        context.log("Javascript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var bodyBuffer=Buffer.from(req.body);
            var boundary=multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
            var parts=multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);
            var temp = "C:/home/site/wwwroot/In.mp4";
            fs.writeFileSync(temp, Buffer(parts[0].data));


    //Actually execute the ffmpeg script
       
       
       var execLineBuilder= "C:/home/site/wwwroot/ffmpeg-5.1.2-essentials_build/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i C:/home/site/wwwroot/In.mp4 C:/home/site/wwwroot/Out.mp4"
       var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;


    //Executing the script
        execSync(execLineBuilder)

    //EVERYTHING WORKS UP UNTIL HERE (chunks array seems to be empty, even though outputting chunk to a file populates
    //That file with data)
    //Storing the chunks of the output mp4 into chunks array

    execSync.on('exit', ()=>{
        chunks = [];
        const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var readStream = fs.createReadStream("C:/home/site/wwwroot/Out.mp4");
            readStream.on('data', (chunk)=> { 
            chunks.push(chunk); 
            resolve("foo");
            }); 
        })
    })

    myPromise.then(()=>{
      context.res={
                status:200,
                body:chunks
            }
    })
    

 
  }catch (e){
        context.res={
            status:500,
            body:e
        }
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

- you can use an npm package called `azure-function-express` this package will basically convert your azure function to an express
- This way you can directly read the mp3 file you saved and send it directly.

```
const  createHandler = require("azure-function-express").createHandler;
const  express = require("express");
const  fs = require('fs');
const  app = express();

app.get("/api/HttpTrigger1", (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':  'video/mp4'});

    let  open = fs.createReadStream('./test.mp3');
    res.send(open);
});
```

[image]

This way you will be able to share the video also running the `ffmpeg` might also be simple